# Tensorflow ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 180, 180, 3), found shape=(None, 180, 3)

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I want to check how the model i've built predicts the image. Data set consists of a lot of pictures 256x256 RGB. The problem itself arises in `model.predict()` function (the model is created without a problem).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import os
import PIL
import tensorflow as tf
import cv2

from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
import pathlib
img_height=180
img_width=180
image=cv2.imread("C:\\anImage\\c000b634560ef3c9211cbf9e08ebce74.jpg")
dimensions = (img_height, img_width)
image = cv2.resize(image, (180,180))
image = np.asarray(image).astype('float32')
print(image.ndim)
valid_dir=pathlib.Path("C:\\diseases\\valid")
data_dir="C:\\diseases\\train"
data_dir=pathlib.Path(data_dir)
image_count = len(list(data_dir.glob('*/*.jpg')))
#grapehealthy = list(data_dir.glob('Grape___healthy/*'))
#print(grapehealthy[0])
#PIL.Image.open(str(grapehealthy[0]))
#print(image_count)
#print(image_count)
# Training split
train_ds = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
    data_dir,
    validation_split=0.2,
    subset="training",
    seed=123,
    image_size=(180, 180),
    batch_size=32)
print(train_ds)
#Validation split
val_ds = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
    valid_dir,
    validation_split=0.2,
    subset="validation",
    seed=123,
    image_size=(180,180),
    batch_size=32)
class_names = train_ds.class_names
num_classes = len(class_names)

model = Sequential([
    layers.Rescaling(1./255 ),
    layers.Conv2D(16, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
    layers.MaxPooling2D(),
    layers.Conv2D(32, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
    layers.MaxPooling2D(),
    layers.Conv2D(64, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
    layers.MaxPooling2D(),
    layers.Flatten(),
    layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    layers.Dense(num_classes)
])
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(
                  from_logits=True),
              metrics=['accuracy'])
model.build((None,180,180,3))
model.summary()
epochs=1
history = model.fit(
  train_ds,
  validation_data=val_ds,
  epochs=epochs
)
model.predict(image)
```

Output:

```
Connected to pydev debugger (build 231.9225.15)
2023-11-26 16:01:45.723637: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:182] This TensorFlow binary is optimized to use available CPU instructions in performance-critical operations.
To enable the following instructions: SSE SSE2 SSE3 SSE4.1 SSE4.2 AVX AVX2 FMA, in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
Backend QtAgg is interactive backend. Turning interactive mode on.
(180, 180, 3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Андрей\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "C:\Users\A4F7~1\AppData\Local\Temp\__autograph_generated_file7nlcn92p.py", line 15, in tf__predict_function
    retval_ = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(step_function), (ag__.ld(self), ag__.ld(iterator)), None, fscope)
    ^^^^^
ValueError: in user code:

    File "C:\Users\Андрей\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\engine\training.py", line 2416, in predict_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "C:\Users\Андрей\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\engine\training.py", line 2401, in step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "C:\Users\Андрей\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\engine\training.py", line 2389, in run_step  **
        outputs = model.predict_step(data)
    File "C:\Users\Андрей\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\engine\training.py", line 2357, in predict_step
        return self(x, training=False)
    File "C:\Users\Андрей\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
        raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
    File "C:\Users\Андрей\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\engine\input_spec.py", line 298, in assert_input_compatibility
        raise ValueError(

    ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 180, 180, 3), found shape=(None, 180, 3)

python-BaseException

Process finished with exit code 1
```

i've tried changing layers, i've thought the problem was with the picture i've chosen, i've tried to change format of it but nothing worked. I guess there is probably problem with layering.

Comment: It seems that it replaces 180 with None

Answer (score 0):

It seems a problem related to the input size.

I suggest to add an input layer as it makes the code and the model easier to understand and more safe:

```
...
img_height=180
img_width=180
channels=3
model = Sequential([
    layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(img_height, img_width, channels)),
    layers.Rescaling(1./255 ),
    layers.Conv2D(16, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
    layers.MaxPooling2D(),
    layers.Conv2D(32, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
    layers.MaxPooling2D(),
    layers.Conv2D(64, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
    layers.MaxPooling2D(),
    layers.Flatten(),
    layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    layers.Dense(num_classes)
])
...
```

Comment: Same error pops up